# Movie where man is unable to die, keeps trying to kill self

Tags: story-identification, movie

A man is unable to die, he keeps on trying to kill himself and, possibly, is also attempted to be murdered, but he is invulnerable. I am dimly recalling the last few minutes, he either jumped off a building or was shot and wakes up realizing he can never die. I think there may have been a Groundhog Day overtone in that some attempts were repeated. I also vaguely remember something about dreaming or dreams and something about his eyes. I think it was in French with English subtitles and was late nineties to early 2000s.

Comment: Any other details about the movie?  In what era was it placed?  Did the guy suddenly get this immortality or he has been like this for ever?

Comment: Parts of this tally up with [Open Your Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Your_Eyes_(1997_film)) "*He had committed suicide at home a few months after falling asleep drunk on the street and was placed in cryonic suspension. At the end of the film, he decides to wake and be resurrected. Convinced his life since the drunken night in the street is simply a nightmarish vision created by Life Extension, César leaps from the roof of the company's high-rise headquarters, and wakes to a female voice telling him to relax and open his eyes.*"

Comment: It was modern times, there were cars and modern glass office buildings.  I don't know if he had recently become immortal or if he had always been.

Comment: It could be "Open Your Eyes" I will look at this movie as soon as I can, which will be several weeks.  The last line sounds tantalizingly like what I remember.  I will repost after I have watched the movie.  Thanks to both of you for your help.

Comment: If that's not it, I vaguely recall a similar Q on another SE where the answer was [The Bothersome Man](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0808185/). There are modern offices, IIRC people there can't dream, and the protagonist throws himself in front of a train but it doesn't work. See if anything in [this trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0DucUDX80Q) looks familiar.

Comment: Walt, thanks for your response, no the trailer doesn't look anything like the movie I saw.  "The Bothersome Man" is silver, gray and white tones - the movie I saw was mainly yellow and brown tones, not only the clothing, buildings and scenes but the background light was light yellow brown as if they had used that as a filter on the camera. Even though this isn't the movie I was thinking of it is one that I will now have to watch!

Comment: So, any update on _Open your eyes_?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same movie! It's *[The Bothersome Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bothersome_Man)*

> As the film begins, Andreas Ramsfjell is underground in a train station. He is watching a couple kiss; however, the kiss lacks any sign of aesthetics - on the contrary, it looks hideous and abominable. Andreas seems to be increasingly unsettled until eventually he steps forward and jumps off the track in front of a subway train and the scene abruptly ends.
>
> In the following scene, he is on a bus which lets him off at a deserted gas station in the middle of nowhere. An older man greets Andreas with a welcome sign and escorts him into a car. From here he makes his way into a seemingly ideal city, where he soon finds himself with a corporate job, a furnished apartment and a beautiful girlfriend. The seemingly perfect life where everyone's needs are met soon proves to be vacuous. Andreas seems to be the only person in the city capable of experiencing sensation and emotion. The only respite from the emptiness is a meaningless materialism.
>
> As the slightly uncomfortable turns into the absurd, Andreas tries to escape, but finds there is no way out of the city. The beginning scene is revealed again in the midst of his misery after he gets his heart broken and he steps out onto the train tracks, only to find that he can survive any suicide attempt. Eventually he meets Hugo, a cleaner who has found a crack in the walls of his basement from which lovely music streams out and children are heard laughing. The two dig frantically, in secret, through the wall and discover it leads into a bright and colorful house, presumably back in the real world.

### Trailer

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should [edit] your answer to include details from the link that shows how it matches the points in the question.